# Javascript get element by id

Tags: javascript

My HTML includes the code:

```
<div id="msg"></div>
```

In its body.

In the head section I then have:

```
var msg = document.getElementByID("msg");
```

But when I then call within a function:

```
msg.innerHTML = "test";
```

It returns an error stating that `msg` is null. What should I do?

Comment: Don't store the element in `msg` globally - get it when you need it and manipulate it then...otherwise leave it alone. So in your function, use your line `var msg = ...` and then manipulate the `innerHTML`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Firstly, you have to consider that JavaScript is case sensitive language, so you should use `getElementById` (note case of last letter). Next, if you get element by id, you should pass ID as an argument (not a tag name):

```
var msg = document.getElementById("msg");
```

You can read more information about this method in **MDN**:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById

Also, one important note is to use this code when the markup is fully loaded, i.e. when your `msg` element is *"visible"* for JavaScript. In order to achieve this, one option is to put your `<script>` tag (with corresponding JavaScript code) to the end of HTML right before `</body>`.

Comment: Yes, sorry, that was my mistake, the getElementById had msg as argument, I fixed "ID" to "id" but still not working

Comment: @DarioPanada It's `Id`, not `id`

Answer (score 2):

> In the head section I then have:
>
> ```
> var msg = document.getElementByID("div");
> ```

Three issues there:

1. If that code is in `head`, but the element is defined in `body`, the element doesn't exist yet when the code is run.
2. The element's `id` is `"msg"`, not `div`. `div` is its tag name, and isn't unique.
3. It's `getElementById`, not `getElementByID`.

If you move your script element containing the code to just before the closing `</body>` tag on your page, and use `document.getElementById("msg")`, you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are calling it before the page has loaded the element. You need to wait for [document ready](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.readyState) or [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onload) to reference the element.

Comment: Hm, so how can I do that exactly?

Comment: Do you look at the links? There is examples there.